# Facebook login on phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have my cordova/ionic based app that I`m building using phonegap online service.
However I cant run the facebook login.everything works nicely on browser but on a real device none of the callbacks are executed.
Also I noticed that window.cordova.plugins is undefined so I assume i am doing something wrong.
I tried installing numerous plugins, and c/p random "solutions".

```
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $stateParams, ngFB) {
    debugger;
    console.log('here');
    ngFB.login({scope: 'email'}).then(
            function(response) {
        debugger;
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            ngFB.api({
                    path: '/me',
                    params: {fields: 'email'}
            }).then(
                    function (user) {
                debugger;
                console.log(user);
            },
            function (error) {
                alert('Facebook error: ' + error.error_description);
            });
        } else {
            alert('Facebook login failed');
        }
    },
    function(error){
        debugger;
    }
    );
});
```

Here is a snippet of my code, and here is my whole project - 
[GitHub](https://github.com/nikksan/ecivic)

Comment: did you tried out this plugin - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Comment: Yeah, but I`m going for this method instead.